# How do I retrieve values from checkboxes in JavaScript, using onchange to trigger a function?

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox, onchange

I'm a High School student who takes a programming course (JavaScript) at school. We just had a test (which I miserably failed), but we are allowed to try again.

I have a couple of checkboxes. They all have an onchange which triggers a function later. I want to retrieve their values when I click on the checkboxes.

I've browsed around here a bit and seen something called jQuery. I have no idea what that is, so I would highly appreciate to get my help in pure JavaScript.

Okay, here is what I have of code. Note: Some variables and such are in Norwegian. I don't think it should be a problem, since I show the references to all.

My inputs (checkboxes):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="tur" value="0" onchange="funcSjekkBoks(this)">
<input type="checkbox" class="tur" value="1" onchange="funcSjekkBoks(this)">
<input type="checkbox" class="tur" value="2" onchange="funcSjekkBoks(this)">
<input type="checkbox" class="tur" value="3" onchange="funcSjekkBoks(this)">
<input type="checkbox" class="tur" value="4" onchange="funcSjekkBoks(this)">
```

I only need their value to be numbers, since I will use those in reference to an array list I have later.

Here is my function:

```
var inputTur = document.getElementsByClassName("tur");
console.log(inputTur);

    function funcSjekkBoks(checkboxEl) {
        var resultatListe = [];
        if (checkboxEl.checked) {
            resultatListe.push(inputTur.value);
            console.log(resultatListe);
        }
        else {
            console.log("usant")
        }
    }
```

What I would like to happen (if all checkboxes are checked from top to bottom):

`resultatListe = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`
When I uncheck a checkbox, it's value will be removed from the array.

Here is what currently happens:
When I check a checkbox I get `[undefined]` in my console, when I uncheck a checkbox I get `usant` (although that is the expected response, I haven't worked with the else part of my if-sentence yet.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will work for you:

```
var resultatListe = [];
function funcSjekkBoks(checkboxEl) {
    var value = parseInt(checkboxEl.value);
    if (checkboxEl.checked) {
        resultatListe.push(value);
        console.log(resultatListe);
    }
    else {
        console.log("usant");
        var indexToRemove = resultatListe.indexOf(value);
        resultatListe.splice(indexToRemove,1);
    }
}
```

You need to keep the array `resultatListe` outside the function other it will be initialized to empty everytime a checkbox is checked/un-checked, triggering the onchange handler. You were getting undefined as you were accessing 'value' property on HTMLCollection object which does not contain that property. Read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputTur = document.getElementsByClassName("tur");
var resultatListe = [];
console.log(inputTur);

        function funcSjekkBoks(checkboxEl) {

            if (checkboxEl.checked) {
                resultatListe.push(parseInt(checkboxEl.value));
            }
            else {
                resultatListe = resultatListe.filter(d => d != checkboxEl.value)
            }
            console.log(resultatListe);
        }
```

There were 2 mistakes in your logic:

1) You need to define `resultatListe` outside the function so that it won't get initialized to an empty array everytime

2) In you code `resultatListe.push(inputTur.value);` inputTur is the HTMLCollection of checkboxes whereas you need the single checkbox.

For the else logic, if the value of each checkbox is going to be unique you can use `array.prototype.filter` method to filter out the value of checkbox from `resultatListe`